# Isolating variables in three-variable equation system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, factoring

I am presented with the following equation system

$x^2 = 8+(y-z)^2$

$y^2 = 12+(z-x)^2$

$z^2 = 24+(x-y)^2$

I don't even know where to start. I am assuming you need to isolate the variables to begin with but even then - I have been unable to reach any sort of progress.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's $$(x-y+z)(x-z+y)=8$$
$$(y-x+z)(y-z+x)=12$$ and
$$(z-x+y)(z-y+x)=24,$$ which gives
$$\prod_{cyc}(x+y-z)^2=48^2.$$
Now, if $\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y-z)=48$ we obtain:
$$y+z-x=6,$$
$$x+z-y=4$$ and
$$x+y-z=2,$$ which gives
$$(x,y,z)=(3,4,5).$$
The second case gives $$(x,y,z)=(-3,-4,-5).$$

Comment: Note that the first two equations' RHS have a common (nonzero) factor, and elimination leads to a linear equation (in three variables) $12(x-y+z) = 8(y-x+z)$.  Presumably the other two pairs of equations give each a similar line equation, so we are reduced to solving a $3\times 3$ linear system.

Comment: Why someone down voted?

Comment: @amWhy:  The answer is only minutes old and being actively edited.  I have faith that Michael will polish it nicely.

Comment: Note Adam that this answer makes use of the factoring of a difference of squares: $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$.  Here, E.g.,$$x^2 = 8+(y-z)^2 \iff x^2 -(y-z)^2 = 8 \iff (x-(y-z))(x+(y-z)) = 8 \iff (x-y+z)(x+y-z) = 8$$  You can do the same with the other two equations, to get what Michael didn't bother to explain to you.  Anyway, @hardmath, I think the three equations Michael provides is best explained by the use of the difference of squares.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: How do you reach $\prod_{cyc}(x+y-z)^2=48^2$ though?

Comment: @Adam Myman I just wrote $(x-y+z)(x-z+y)(y-x+z)(y-z+x)(z-x+y)(z-y+x)=8\cdot12\cdot24$, which is $(x+y-z)^2(x+z-y)^2(y+z-x)^2=48^2.$

Comment: You are welcome!